# Rational points of an circle centred at $(\pi,2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, circles, coordinate-systems, alternative-proof

> A point $(a,b)$ is called a **rational point** when $a$ and $b$ are both rationals.
>
> Find the maximum possible rational points on a circle centred at $(\pi,2)$.
>
> Answer: $2$

**My attempt:**

Suppose there exist $3$ (or more) such rational points. Consider a triangle formed by three points.

It is fairly easy to prove that such a "rational triangle" has a rational point as the circumcentre.

But this contradicts the fact that the actual circumcentre is, in fact, not a rational point. Hence, there can exist at most two rational points.

*The existence of two rational points*:

Let the radius of the circle be $r$. Then, the equation of the circle happens to be
$$(x-\pi)^2+(y-2)^2=r^2=r_r+r_i$$
Where $r_r$ denotes the rational part of $r^2$ and the $r_i$ denotes the irrational part of $r^2$.

Let $(a,b)$ be a rational point on this circle.

It is fairly easy to arrive at
$$r_r=a^2+(b-2)^2$$
And
$$r_i=\pi^2-2\pi a$$

Now, for certain values of $r$, each of them generates a single value each of $r_r$ and $r_i$. And, each value of $r_i$ generates a single value of $a$, which on substituting in the second equation, gives two values of $b$.

Hence, there may exist two such points.

> I somehow feel this proof of mine isn't *exactly* correct. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Other solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: You should expand on the "fairly easy" part, since that is essentially where all the proof lies... Also, to prove the existence you need only give a concrete example. For instance, you can set the radius to $\sqrt{\pi^2 + 4}$, and point out two rational points.

Comment: BTW, what's the "rational part" of say $\sqrt{2}$? Is it $0$, or $1$ or maybe it is $1.4142$? That notion of "xyz part" of something makes sense when that part is uniquely determined, or maybe there are only very few possible values. But here, $r_r$ can be **any** rational number and an appropriate irrational $r_i$ does exist. So that notion doesn't make sense here, IMO. That part of the proof is indeed strange (let's say I don't understand it at all, but I don't understand everything).

As Trebor said, all you need to do is find one circle that gives you 2 rational points.

Comment: @Trebor Well, this actually came on an OMR based test, so the above is a rough sketch of the proof in my mind.

Comment: @Ingix Uhh, now that you mention it, I am not exactly sure as to what I mean by that irrational part. It's getting stranger by the minute. Oof.

Comment: You can solve that "rational part" thing with Hamel basis, but that's way past the supposed difficulty of the problem..

Comment: @Trebor Yup. Haven't heard of Hamel basis yet, nor is it in our syllabus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x-\pi)^2+(y-2)^2=r^2$ and $(w-\pi)^2+(z-2)^2=r^2$ means by subtraction that $(x-\pi)^2-(w-\pi)^2$ is rational which means $x=w$ since clearly $x+w-2 \pi \ne 0$ irrational, when $x,w \in \mathbb Q$

This clearly gives at most two possible values for $y$ (since there is at most one $x$ for which the rational point is on the circle) and one can clearly get two for appropriate radiuses

Comment: (+1) Thanks! It actually should be "radii" instead if "radiuses".